# Python tkinter snake game restart

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I`m trying to code a snake game in python using tkinter but I am not able to find a solution regarding a restart function.
In short, I want to create a button with the text "Restart" or "Play again" only when you die and once you press the Restart button the game starts again.

Here is the code:

```
GAMEWIDTH = 900

GAMEHEIGHT = 600

GAMESPEED = 70

ITEMSSIZE = 30

BODYWIDTH = 2

BODYCOLOR = "#03fc0b"

FOODCOLOR = "yellow"

BACKGROUNDCOLOR = "#cf03fc"

def snake_game():
    global Sarpe, Mancare, directie, points, points_increment

    def snake_turn(snake, food):
        a, b = snake.coordonate[0]

        if directie == "up":
            b -= ITEMSSIZE
        elif directie == "down":
            b += ITEMSSIZE
        elif directie == "left":
            a -= ITEMSSIZE
        elif directie == "right":
            a += ITEMSSIZE

        snake.coordonate.insert(0, (a, b))
        cube = tablou.create_rectangle(a, b, a + ITEMSSIZE, b + ITEMSSIZE, fill=BODYCOLOR)
        snake.cubes.insert(0, cube)
        if a == food.coordonate[0] and b == food.coordonate[1]:
            global points
            points += 1
            points_increment.config(text="Points:{}".format(points))
            tablou.delete("food")
            food = Mancare()

        else:
            del snake.coordonate[-1]
            tablou.delete(snake.cubes[-1])
            del snake.cubes[-1]

        if verify_collisions(snake):
            you_died()
        else:
            snakeGUI.after(GAMESPEED, snake_turn, snake, food)

    def change_movement(new_directie):
        global directie

        if new_directie == "left":
            if directie != "right":
                directie = new_directie
        elif new_directie == "right":
            if directie != "left":
                directie = new_directie
        elif new_directie == "up":
            if directie != "down":
                directie = new_directie
        elif new_directie == "down":
            if directie != "up":
                directie = new_directie

    def verify_collisions(snake):
        a, b = snake.coordonate[0]

        if a < 0 or a >= GAMEWIDTH:
            return True
        elif b < 0 or b >= GAMEHEIGHT:
            return True
        for snake_body in snake.coordonate[1:]:
            if a == snake_body[0] and b == snake_body[1]:
                return True

    def you_died():
        tablou.delete(ALL)
        tablou.create_text(tablou.winfo_width() / 2, tablou.winfo_height() / 2, font=("gameplay", 90), text="GAME OVER",
                           fill="#03fc1c", tag="game over")


    class Sarpe:
        def __init__(self):
            self.body_size = BODYWIDTH
            self.coordonate = []
            self.cubes = []

            for i in range(0, BODYWIDTH):
                self.coordonate.append([0, 0])

            for a, b in self.coordonate:
                cube = tablou.create_rectangle(a, b, a + ITEMSSIZE, b + ITEMSSIZE, fill=BODYCOLOR, tag="snake")
                self.cubes.append(cube)

    class Mancare:
        def __init__(self):
            a = random.randint(0, (GAMEWIDTH / ITEMSSIZE) - 1) * ITEMSSIZE
            b = random.randint(0, (GAMEHEIGHT / ITEMSSIZE) - 1) * ITEMSSIZE

            self.coordonate = [a, b]
            tablou.create_oval(a, b, a + ITEMSSIZE, b + ITEMSSIZE, fill=FOODCOLOR, tag="food")

    snakeGUI = Tk()
    snakeGUI.title("Snake")
    snakeGUI.resizable(False, False)

    points = 0
    directie = "down"

    points_increment = Label(snakeGUI, text="Points:{}".format(points), font=("consolas", 40))
    points_increment.pack()

    tablou = Canvas(snakeGUI, bg="#cf03fc", height=GAMEHEIGHT, width=GAMEWIDTH)
    tablou.pack()

    snakeGUI.update()

    snakeGUI_width = snakeGUI.winfo_width()
    snakeGUI_height = snakeGUI.winfo_height()
    screen_width = snakeGUI.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = snakeGUI.winfo_screenheight()

    a = int((screen_width / 2) - (snakeGUI_width / 2))
    b = int((screen_height / 2) - (snakeGUI_height / 2))

    snakeGUI.geometry(f"{snakeGUI_width}x{snakeGUI_height}+{a}+{b}")

    snakeGUI.bind("<Left>", lambda event: change_movement("left"))
    snakeGUI.bind("<Right>", lambda event: change_movement("right"))
    snakeGUI.bind("<Up>", lambda event: change_movement("up"))
    snakeGUI.bind("<Down>", lambda event: change_movement("down"))

    snake = Sarpe()
    food = Mancare()

    snake_turn(snake, food)

    snakeGUI.mainloop()

snake_game()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you could put the main events in a loop, and when you die and press the restart button, you could continue to the loop and do the events all over again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not design whole program features here; you should think about what you expect are the logical steps to solve the problem, [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) each, try to write the code, try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) or at least [isolate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) any problem that comes up, and then you will be able to ask a suitably *specific* question.

Comment: At the very least, you should read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand how to show your code exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

in the part where you defined the game over screen just add snake_game() to call the function
also this might start an infinite loop of starting the game after you die if you dont add a button to start the new game

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the restart button to your project by making 3 changes to your code. first is by creating a restart button titled `restart_button` after you created the canvas. This should look like the following...

```
restart_button = Button(snakeGUI, text = "Start New Game", command = start_new_game)
```

I then placed the button in the window by adding it to the `you_died` function. Below is an example of what this change will look like.

```
def you_died():
    tablou.delete(ALL)
    tablou.create_text(tablou.winfo_width() / 2, tablou.winfo_height() / 2, font=("gameplay", 90), text="GAME OVER", fill="#03fc1c", tag="game over")
    restart_button.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.7, anchor = "center")
```

After that, I created the `start_new_game` function that was referenced in the button created earlier. This function removes the button, clears the canvas, and resets everything back to defaults. An example of this function is shown below.

```
def start_new_game(): 
    restart_button.place_forget()
    tablou.delete(ALL)

    global directie, points
    directie = "down"
    points = 0
    points_increment.config(text="Points:{}".format(points))
    snake = Sarpe()
    food = Mancare()
    snake_turn(snake, food)
```

You can also improve the game by placing the button upon launching the game. This way you don't have to start playing immediately upon launching the game, and you can utilize the `start_new_game` function to initialize all the variables for the initial game as well. I would even improve it further by adding a 3-second countdown timer before the game starts so you can position your hands on the arrow keys before the game starts.

Answer (score -1):

I have not used this logic with tkinter before, but you could define the WHOLE thing as system, then call system when you lose, so it does the loop all over again!

Comment: Thank you! I will try this!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. You should only attempt to answer questions that are clear to you and which meet the requirements described in [ask], and for which you have a concrete answer in mind. Ideally you should be able to write some code that demonstrates your idea, and explain how the code implements that idea.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).